# new line at Text Box at winform

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I want to pass a string into a method in `form1` class every time an event occurs in another class and then I want to print some text as multi-lined in a `TextBox` in the Windows Form associated with `form1` class.

The thing is I'm getting all the text in that `TextBox` in a single line and want to print it on a new line:

```
private void myEvt_valueChnaged(string s)
{
     textBox1.Invoke(new Action(() => textBox1.Text = s ));
}
```

I tried to use `+=` and then I got the text later in the line and not below the line .
I also tried to add `+="/n/r" + s` and it was printed as is in the Text Box

Then I tried using `+= Environment.NewLine()  + s` and got the error: `Environment.NewLine cannot be used like a method .`

Comment: Because `Environment.NewLine` is a property not a method.

Comment: You cannot display a multi-line string in a single-line textbox.  The trivial solution is to set the textbox' Multiline property to True.

Answer (score 0):

"\n " is good enough for a new line in c#.
String newline = "\n "
textBox1.Invoke(new Action(() => textBox1.Text = newline + s ));

Comment: Hi , it didn't solve the issue , the new text replace the old text at the same line .

Answer (score 0):

You should set the **Multiline** property of the textbox control to **True** and then just call this:

```
 textBox1.Invoke(new Action(() => textBox1.Text = String.Concat(textBox1.Text, Environment.NewLine, s)));
```

if you want to append the text in a new line and maintain the already present text. Otherwise you can use this to put simply the text in the new line:

```
textBox1.Invoke(new Action(() => textBox1.Text = String.Concat(Environment.NewLine, s)));
```

Note that `Environment.NewLine` is a property not a method.

Comment: The result of the first command is replacing the old line at new line . The result of the second command is printing the new text at new line but at every iteration the text as number of iterations , F.E : at the first iteration - print the text one time , at the second iteration - print the text two times ... and didn't solve the issue

Comment: The first command doesn't replace the old line with a new one, but it appends the new text in a new line inside the text box. It is equivalent to: `textBox1.Invoke(new Action(() => textBox1.Text += Environment.NewLine + s));`. Your error was related to the fact that you should set Multiline to true and don't use Environment.NewLine() as a method.

Comment: i understand my original errors . i dont understand how those solutions solve it because both : textBox1.Invoke(new Action(() => textBox1.Text = String.Concat(Environment.NewLine, s))); , textBox1.Invoke(new Action(() => textBox1.Text += Environment.NewLine + s)); are adding the related texts - s , as number of iteration  . F.E : at the first iteration print : hello , at the second iteration print : hello (new line) hello , at third iteration :   hello (new line) hello (new line) hello and so on ...

Comment: Isn't it what would you like to print? Then I think that I don't understand what is really your issue...What output would you like to obtain in the textbox?

Comment: the output i want to obtain at textbox is one sentence every time the method occurred . what really printed at textbox is at the first time the method occurred the text printed one time  , at the second iteration the text printed 2 times and not one time as expected  , at third iteration the text printed 3 times and not one time as expected  . After 3 iteration the method occurred total texts in text box are 6 and not 3 .